# Delete Grafana default dashboards

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I have created new dashboards in Grafana.

I need to delete the default dashboards in Grafana UI. ( E.g:- Disk Usage , Disk operations , System overview , Cross server graphs) . As there were many  dashboards get listed.

In settings  i don't find any delete option for this dashboards.

But I can able to delete the dashboards which i have created (customized)  `settings --> delete dashboard`